# "log" tag should be made a synonym of "logs"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

43 questions are tagged with [log](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) and 1004 questions are tagged with [logs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs) which also has a nice description to come with.

I propose that [log](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) be made a synonym of [logs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs) as it is more established and they both share the same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merged, [log](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) → [logs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs) synonym added.